# color picker in configuration Mismatched anonymous define() module in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, configurable-product, color-swatches, system-configuration

when I add color picker to admin system configuration i got this kind of error can any one know about how can I rsolve it.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your error you want to add `adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml` on path  `Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml` in your module and add below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

if you used `<link src="jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js"/>` on head tag on above file then remove it.

then run the basic CLI commands and check.

Answer (score 0):

**As per magento 2 standards, you will required requirejs-config.js to add custom javascript Create requirejs-config.js in app/code/vendor/module-name/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js**

```
    var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        customscript:'Vendor_ModuleName::js/custom'
    }
}
```

};

then create custom.js : **app/code/Vendor/modulename/view/adminhtml/web/js**